# Isomorphism between tensor product $V^*\bigotimes_\mathbb{K} W$ and linear maps $\text{Hom}_\mathbb{K}(V,W)$

Tags: vector-spaces, tensor-products, dual-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space generated by $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ over a field $\mathbb{K}$ ($\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) and let $V^*$ be its dual generated by the corresponding $v^1,\ldots,v^n$. Let $W$ be a vector space generated by $w_1,\ldots,w_m$ over $\mathbb{K}$ and let $W^*$ be its dual generated by the corresponding $w^1,\ldots,w^m$.

Consider the map $f:V^*\bigotimes_\mathbb{K} W\longrightarrow\text{Hom}_\mathbb{K}(V,W)$ defined by $f(\beta)x=\sum_{k=1}^m\beta(\iota_x,w^k)w_k$ for all $x\in V$, where $\iota_x:V^*\longrightarrow\mathbb{K}$ is the linear map defined by $\iota_x(f)=f(x)$ for all $f\in V^*$.

Consider also the map $g:\text{Hom}_\mathbb{K}(V,W)\longrightarrow V^*\bigotimes_\mathbb{K} W$ defined by $g(\alpha)=\sum_{j=1}^n v^j\otimes(\alpha v_j)$.

I want to show that $f$ is an isomorphism between $V^*\bigotimes_\mathbb{K} W$ and $\text{Hom}_\mathbb{K}(V,W)$ by showing that $g$ and $f$ are inverse to each other, ie. that $g\circ f=\text{id}_{V^*\bigotimes_\mathbb{K} W}$ and $f\circ g=\text{id}_{\text{Hom}_\mathbb{K}(V,W)}$. I have been trying for several hours to compute these compositions but I don’t seem to come to a conclusion. Could somebody help me out with this problem? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: A way I like to see that $f$ is an isomorphism is to show it is injective by inspecting a basis and using knowledge of the dimensions of the respective spaces. To see that the maps are inverse, a good direction to go is to look at how they act on a basis of elementary tensors for $V^* \otimes_k W$.

Comment: There is some amount of weirdness with your notations. If $\beta\in V^*\otimes W$, what is $\beta(\iota_x,w^k)$?

Comment: You do not need bases to define the maps. The same maps exist for modules over commutative rings... Just use the universal mapping property of the tensor product. Then do a dimension count at the end for the finite-dimensional vector space case to see that you have an isomorphism.

Comment: It's difficult to understand your notation for $f$. However, the correct map from $V^* \otimes W$ to Hom$(V,W)$ can be written out as
$$
f\left(\sum_{j,k = 1}^m a_{jk} v^j \otimes w_k \right)(x) = \sum_{j,k = 1}^m a_{jk} w_k v^j(x)
$$

Comment: My best guess here is that for $\beta = v^* \otimes w$, $\beta(\iota_x,w^k) = \iota_x(v^*) \cdot w^k(w)$.